# Uploaded images appear broken in WP 4.4

Tags: images

After upgrading to WordPress 4.4, any images we upload using Add Media appear as broken in the Media Library.

*We're using HTTP, not HTTPS.*

I have tried:

1. Chmodding to 744 `/wp-content/uploads/` and all subdirectories.
2. Chmodding to 755 `/wp-content/uploads/` and all subdirectories.
3. Chmodding to 644 all files in `/wp-content/uploads/`.
4. De-activating all plugins and switching to TwentyThirteen theme.
5. Adding the following code to the child theme's `functions.php`:

   ```
   add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', function( $attr ) {
       if ( isset( $attr['sizes'] ) ) unset( $attr['sizes'] );
       if ( isset( $attr['srcset'] ) ) unset( $attr['srcset'] );
       return $attr;
   }, PHP_INT_MAX );
   add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX );
   add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX );
   remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );
   ```

Refer:

1. [How to Fix Image Upload Issue in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/)
2. [after upgrade to 4.4 media files are not showing](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-upgrade-to-44-media-files-are-not-showing)

The issue remains.

An example image that appears broken is: http://www.arcadenightclub.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Xmas-Festivus-Arcade-Nightclub.jpg

Comment: "Can't upload" and "apear broken" are two hugely different things so please clarify which is the actuall problem, with relevvant error message and image urls if applicable

Comment: The code snippet in part 5. actually comes from my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211376/26350). It looks like your site has currently problems connecting to the database.