# Specific image size is being generated without being registered

Tags: images

I am looking at uploads folder and I see that 768x510 images are being generated. I am using my own theme and I don't have that size registered, there isnt anything registered in media options in dashboard beside thumbnail (200x200) and it seems like it isnt registered in plugins either (I have used advanced search in Sublime text to search in all files).

These are my registered  sizes:

```
   add_image_size('img_big', 1200, 700, true);
   add_image_size('img_medium', 590, 388, true);
   add_image_size('img_thumb', 285, 180, true;
   add_image_size('img_icon', 85, 85, true);
```

Listing registered sizes with the following code shows my sizes and nothing else

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; 
print '<pre>'; 
print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ); 
print '</pre>';
```

But doing this

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(get_intermediate_image_sizes()); ?>
</pre>
```

gives me this

```
Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
    [4] => img_big
    [5] => img_medium
    [6] => img_thumb
    [7] => img_icon
)
```

Why is medium_large being registered and how to stop it?
Having this in functions.php does nothing (I tested by uploading, it still generates that size)

```
add_action('init', 'remove_plugin_image_sizes');

function remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
  remove_image_size('medium_large');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new feature is for responsive designs that comes with WP 4.4. Check if you have any plugin that related to responsive. If you don't have not any, check these both:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/

[How do I disable responsive images in WP 4.4?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211375/how-do-i-disable-responsive-images-in-wp-4-4)