# How to change the markup Wordpress inserts for post images

Tags: functions, images, html5

I am developing a theme with Underscores for WordPress.

When the user adds an image using the TinyMCE editor the following code is inserted:

```
<img class="wp-image-45 size-full aligncenter" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/process.png" alt="process" width="849" height="91" />
```

When I look at the final page generated by Wordpress, the HTML appears in the DOM

```
<img class="wp-image-45 size-full aligncenter" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/process.png" alt="process" width="849" height="91" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/process.png 849w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/process-300x32.png 300w, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/process-768x82.png 768w" sizes="(max-width: 849px) 100vw, 849px">
```

I have created a function to generate a thumbnail with a width of 300px:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'images_theme_setup' );
function images_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'preload-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
}
```

Now I want to use Pil (https://github.com/gilbitron/Pil) compatible markup to serve images so I can serve the `preload-thumb` and then serve the larger image

I need to change to the markup to match this below

```
<figure class="pil">
    <img src="img/my-image.jpg" data-pil-thumb-url="img/thumb-my-image.jpg" data-full-width="5616" data-full-height="3744" alt="">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you could hook into the filter [`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) like this:

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
  $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
  $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='align-$align'>";
  $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' />";
  $html5 .= "</figure>";
  return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

For additional tags like `data-pil-thumb-url` and `data-full-width` and `data-full-height`you could add the appropriate code inside that function and add them to the `$html5` string.

See also [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/insert-images-within-figure-element-from-media-uploader/) for an example featuring a caption `<figcaption>` at css-tricks or check [this](http://synapticism.com/dev/experimenting-with-html5-image-markup-and-shortcodes-in-wordpress/) more detailed 'walk through'.

Comment: How can I get a medium size, $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'medium' ); returns blank

Comment: For correctness, title and alt attributes are not the same thing. After the $url argument $size, $alt are available for the function, if someone cares to use them.

Answer (score 2):

There's a filter called [`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) that lets you specify the markup. You will also need [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) to retrieve width and height. It is called like this (untested):

```
   add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_231693_img_markup', 10, 7 );
   function wpse_231693_img_markup ($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $url, $size ) {
       $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata ($id);
       $url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
       $html = '<figure class="pil"><img src="' . $url . 
               '" data-pil-thumb-url="XXX" data-full-width="' . $metadata['width'] .
               '" data-full-height="' . $metadata['height'] .
               '" alt="' . $alt . '"></figure>';
       return $html;
   }
```

You will need some clever regex to construct XXX from $url, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: As I understand it, image_send_to_editor only works on tinyMCE but then wordpress will replace it with their responsive image's markup. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/

Comment: Also, it returns 'unexpected T_RETURN' for 'return $html;'

Comment: As I said: ''untested". There was a ' missing. I've corrected that. Your link points to an additional filter that adds the srcset attribute. That could probably be overriden. If `$url` doesn't pass try adding `$url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);`

Comment: Apologies. Their is also another ' missing for $metadata['width'].  I added `$url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);` - within TinyMCE the url is displayed, however within the rendered post page the url has disappeared.

Comment: Do you sitll have the `srcset` attribute? You could try to disable the responsive stuff. That might also leave the `src` alone. Here's a discussion about that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211375/how-do-i-disable-responsive-images-in-wp-4-4