# Automatically Insert alt attribute above image has h2

Tags: images, media

When inserting an image in a WordPress post, I would like that it automatically add the alt text of the image above the image as h2.

Example, when inserting an image, WordPress ads this into the post:

```
<img src="" alt="Hello" />
```

What I would like is inserting:

```
<h2>Hello</h2>
<img src="" alt="Hello" />
```

Thank you for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution using this  [How to change the markup Wordpress inserts for post images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231693/how-to-change-the-markup-wordpress-inserts-for-post-images)

My final code is:

```
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'add_custom_data_attribute_send_to_editor', 10, 8 );
function add_custom_data_attribute_send_to_editor( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ){  
    if( $id > 0 ){
        $post = get_post( $id );
              $html = str_replace( "<img src", "<h2>$alt</h2><img src", $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
```