# $content is empty while using DOMDocument

Tags: functions, filters, the-content

I'm trying to modify the Image Output on my Wordpress-Site to replace src and srcset with their "data-" Equivalent while adding an additional class. Therefor I'm using DOMDocument and filter for imgs. Here's my code:

```
function image_manipulation( $content ) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

    $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
        $orig_src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        $orig_srcset = $img->getAttribute('srcset');
        $existing_class = $img->getAttribute('class');

        $img->setAttribute('src','');
        $img->setAttribute('srcset','');

        $img->setAttribute('class',$existing_class . ' js-lazy-image');
        $img->setAttribute('data-src',$orig_src);
        $img->setAttribute('data-srcset',$orig_srcset);
    }

    $html = $document->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'image_manipulation');
```

Everything works on posts, but if I open any page, I get an error saying "`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in functions.php on line 73`" (line 73 is the line with `loadHTML` in it).

I'm stucked... Thanks for any good hints in advance!

Comment: By page, do you mean the `page` post type, or simply other pages like homepage or archives?

Comment: Is the `utf8_decode` necessary?

Comment: What about these hooks?
 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211376/126253 I think you don't need strip attributes manually

Comment: do those pages have content? if not, you can just add a check `if(empty($content)) return $content;`

Comment: @jack-johansson I mean the `page` post type, like my normal "about" page. The error doesn't occure on `archive` pages btw.
@tom-j-nowell It isn't necessarly, but the error remains the same if I delete this part...

Comment: @inarilo I should realy go to bed -.-
I tried to fix this like two hours long an didn't recognized I was on several test pages without content. You sir saved my evening :D

Comment: yw :) p.s. i'm a Miss ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, in this case: You Miss saved my evening ;)

Comment: @inarilo please make it a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pages that are giving errors have no content, you can deal with it by adding a check at the start of the function:

```
function image_manipulation( $content ) {
  if(empty($content)) return $content;
  //rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works great with:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```