# medium_large image size not displaying properly on the frontend?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, responsive, media-settings

I have added a code snippet to utilize the "medium_large" thumbnail size. This works fine on the back end and I can select this image size in all image blocks. It also seems to output the correct file in the HTML. **However**, the actual image downloaded to the browser is either Large or Full Size (whichever is smaller). I am confirming this by looking at the Sources tab in Chrome Inspect. I have also verified that the medium_large file exists on the server.

As shown in the attached screenshot, the source file in HTML is "outdoor_group-768x517.jpg", which is the medium_large image. But the current source is shown as "outdoor_group.jpg", the full size image.

[image: Chrome Inspect Screenshot]

Is there some special behavior of the medium_large image size that I don't know about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove one srcset entry from wp\_get\_attachment\_image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412851/remove-one-srcset-entry-from-wp-get-attachment-image)

Comment: I flagged this question as a duplicate of that question since I think it helps. It's not the same _question_ but the core problem is the same and my answer applies to both. The reason an unexpected source is being loaded is almost certainly that the `sizes` attribute is incorrect. You haven't shared the code snippet you used though, so I'm not certain if the code in my answer is relevant.

Comment: I believe that you're partially correct, that the problem lies with the srcset attribute. I've traced it down to how srcset responds to the resolution of the browser screen, which I've learned is **not** the same as the pixel width of the viewport. There is a good description of the issue on [this blog post](https://livefiredev.com/srcset-not-working-getting-wrong-images/).

To test this theory, I loaded up the page in question in a browser on my 2nd monitor, which has a lower resolution (1920x1080) than my PixelBook (2400x1600). At the lower resolution, the desired 768px image was loaded.

Comment: You still need to have a correct sizes attribute. The srcset attribute does not respond to the browser, the sizes attribute does. That blog post you linked is premised on the idea that the sizes attribute is already correct. The default sizes attribute from WordPress will not be correct so you still need to set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem recently on a project, and the answer is to disable responsive image markup. Simply add the below code into your theme's `functions.php` and you are golden:

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', '__return_false' );
```

Ref: [How do I disable responsive images in WP 4.4?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211375/how-do-i-disable-responsive-images-in-wp-4-4)

Afterwards, you can insert the Medium Large a.k.a. `medium_large` images (if enabled) into your post editor and they will load correctly on the frontend.

For the record I think the Medium Large size is very underrated, and saves tons of time. We use it by default in our free [HoverCraft](https://github.com/littlebizzy/hovercraft) theme for featured images, and also the default size for inserting media too. This is a special image size in WordPress because the width is fixed at 768px wide with auto-height depending on the ratio of the image file you uploaded, which makes theming and layout very easy to automate.